# Подключение матрицы от ноутбука к raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

Подскажите, есть некоторое количество экранов от ноутбуков.
Хочу подключить к raspberry pi.
Что нужно? Приобрести скалер? И если да, то какой, есть ли универсальные?

Answer (score 2):

есть универсальные скаллеры но нужно смотреть datasheet дисплея для выбора скалера,а есть специальный переходник для raspberry pi на gpio пины называется RASPBERRY HAT